# class and id bugs in <div> and <img> tags

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I am really a bad coder.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong...
The CSS is not working...
Thank you!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#main_table {
    height:100px;
    width: 300px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:red;
};

.sub_table {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
};

.image {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:15px;
    max-width:300px;
};

</style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="main_table">
    <div class="sub_table">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
            <img class="image" src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_table">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">
            <img class="image" src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The .image class is not working...

Comment: Why are you putting semicolon in css after } ?

Comment: `};` - you're getting your syntaxes confused :)

Answer (score 2):

used to this remove `;` as like this

```
#main_table {
    height:100px;
    width: 300px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:red;
}

.sub_table {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.image {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:15px;
    max-width:300px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS parser stops when it encounters a really bad error. In your case it's the semicolon after the closing brace of each rule.

Instead of this

```
.sub_table {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
};
```

Use this

```
.sub_table {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow; 
}
```